# How to get an included js file's contents without xhr?

Tags: javascript, html

is this possible?

```
<html>
  <script src="local.js>
  <script>
    // get contents of local.js file here without doing an ajax call?
  </script>
</html>
```

local.js resides on the same server, and I know that by doing an xhr call I can get its contents (if not on file://).

But, as it is already requested synchronously by the browser, its contents is known to the document so I hope there is a way to access it? The document.scripts collection was no help to me.

Somewhat like getting innerHTML (which works for scripts defined in-page)?

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure on how to get the included javascript code, nor why you would need this, but how about going the other direction?

Instead of having a script tag, make a XHR call to the file and eval its contents + keep its contents as a variable also.

**Disclaimer: I cannot see why you would need this, nor would I actually suggest you use this method, but it's a work-around.

Answer (score 1):

Are you assuming XHR will not use the cached version?  It will, there may be a request, but it should be fast (reuse the same HTTP connection) and return 304 (not modified).  So the cached version will be used unless your JavaScript file's HTTP response headers prohibit or do not specify caching directives (but usually they should).

Answer (score -1):

I suspect that while the contents of the script are known to the *browser*, they're not known to the *document*, and are therefore not accessible via the DOM API. So you will have to use the XHR approach. With a bit of luck, if you ensure the script is properly cached, the XHR request will pull the script contents from the local cache anyway.